# turtle graphics module missing from Python 3.6 on centos 7?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos7, turtle-graphics

I've trawled google and this site but can't seem to find anything relating specifically to this problem. Summary is:

- Installed Centos 7 on a machine over Christmas to re-purpose it as a dev machine and get my head around Python.
- Installed Python 3.6 this morning.
- Started writing a Python script that requires turtle graphics:

> ```
> import turtle
>
> def draw_something():
>     print("Hello world")
>
> draw_something()
> ```

- Which throws this exception:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

I thought turtle comes as part of the Centos 7 install of Python3.6.

Note, I got the Python3.6 rpm from here:

> sudo yum install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

Is this something specific to Centos 7 or am I being a dummy?

Thanks

Comment: Python by default comes without most extra modules, you can install them by yourself using the command `pip install turtle`.

Comment: So when I check modules using `pip3.6 search turtle` I get this: `turtle (0.0.2)  - Turtle is an HTTP proxy whose purpose is to throttle connections to...`. This isn't the turtle I was expecting......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've figured out what was happening.

The tkinter package for Python 3.6 was missing and this is a dependency for turtle.

> sudo yum -y install python36u-tkinter

This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you run `pip search turtle` and read through the descriptions the `PythonTurtle` modual sounds like the one you are missing so just run `pip3 install PythonTurtle`

Comment: Nothing there: `[robster970@centos bin]$ pip3.6 install PythonTurtle
Collecting PythonTurtle
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PythonTurtle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PythonTurtle
`